# Firefox <dd> text-indent element woes

Tags: css, firefox

So, I was just playing around making some page for fun. I cannot seem to get firefox 4 to not indent a <dd> tag! It completely ignores the text-indent property.

Is this just me? Has anyone else hit this problem? I'm trying to decide if it's me or the browser.

Works fine in Chrome

Comment: http://w3fools.com/ <- A response to the reference to w3schools given in your site's html.

Comment: Take a look at a standards-compliant web tutorial site: http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlintermediate/definitionlists/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm confident the problem is one or both of these issues:

- That page doesn't have a doctype so the browser is using [Quirks Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Quirks_Mode_Behavior).
  Try adding as the very first line `<!DOCTYPE html>` to use Standards Mode.
- You haven't wrapped those [`<dt>` and `<dd>` elements inside a `<dl>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3). Fixed code:

  ```
  <dl>
      <dt>
          <a href="index.xml">Sample Data</a>
      </dt>
      <dd>
          This is just a list of CDs, costs, etc.
      </dd>
  </dl>
  ```

Comment: dl's totally new to me. Always felt weird not wrapping that stuff. Also, not specifying the doctype is a huge beginner's mistake. Will update and report back.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. I'm a dunce.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you got this sorted out, but what happened there is that in quirks mode the following CSS rules are applied to web pages in Gecko (from http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/quirk.css ):

```
:not(dl) > dd {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

:not(dl) > dd:before {
  display: inline;
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: 1px;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "\A  ";
  -moz-margin-end: 40px;
}
```

and you were seeing the space and margin-end of that `:before` pseudo-element.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for finding the actual reason for that margin.